# Python code runs through entire switcher statement

Tags: python, switch-statement

I'm coding a bot using the discord.py api, was trying to simulate switch/cases for different commands to the bot

I read online that I can use `switcher = { *some value* : *function* }` to simulate switch/cases, but on specific values, its runs every function instead of the appropriate one

```
async def command_switcher(argument, message, parameters):
    switcher= {
        ">autovc": await autovc_command_switcher(parameters[1], message, 
         parameters) if (len(parameters) > 1) else await 
         autovc_invalid(message),
        ">help": await default_help(message),
        ">vcgroup": await autovc_invalid(message)
    }
    return switcher.get(argument, "Invalid")
```

I call the `command_switcher` and pass in an argument, if the argument is `">help"`, then it properly only runs the `default_help()` function, but if I pass in `">autovc"` it runs all 3 functions

**Edit**: also, if I switch the order of the entries, it still has the same result: `">help"` still only runs itself, and `">autovc"` still runs all 3

**Edit 2**: **Solved** thanks for the comments, while trying to create a proper MCVE as advised, and seeing the comment that dict values are the function objects, I figured out I was incorrectly calling the functions as opposed to referencing the function object itself. I was also having some issues with async/await, but the comment linking me to https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html cleared that up for me as well

Comment: is there a concept of `break;` statement after each case?

Comment: no, how would I do that? everything I looked up about this type of thing didn't include any form of `break;` outside of using a comma to indicate the next case

Comment: Well, each of the values of that dictionary is evaluated anyway. Alternatively, you might try returning the function itself and calling it outside of the dict. Difficult for the first case, though, where the parameter is different.

Comment: Please post a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also note that in the original "dict-based switch" idiom, the dicts values are the function objects, not the results of function calls, ie : `def foo(): return 42; s = {"foo": foo}; s["foo"]();`

Comment: Not sure if/how `async/await` changes the story here, though. Are you 100% sure that sometimes only one of the "branches" is executed?

Comment: some info: https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments, especially @brunodesthuilliers, solved my issue

Comment: And that’s why it’s dangerous to sell dict as a “Python switch”. It’s not, and it’s merely an idiomatic use.